# PyQt5 all button signals/events?

Tags: python-3.x, button, widget, pyqt5

The signal for MOUSE1 on the button is widget.clicked, what are the ones for MOTION and MOUSE2? Also if anyone knows a site with all signals listed it would really help

```
import sys, pyautogui

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


def pressed_mouse2():
    pass


def window():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    root = QMainWindow()
    root.setGeometry(200, 200, 500, 500)
    root.setWindowTitle('Test')
    root.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
    root.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)

    button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(root)

    #i need here to signal when user has pressed on MOUSE2 on the button
    button.clicked.connect(clicked)
    button.move(50,50)

    root.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

window()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to connect the button's `clicked` signal to your function.

```
button.clicked.connect(pressed_mouse2)
```

Now when you click the button you can execute any code here:

```
def pressed_mouse2():
    print('Button clicked')
```

There are many kinds of widgets, each with different signals. You can find them in the Qt documentation. [Here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#signals) are the signals for QAbstractButton, which is inherited by QPushButton.

There is no predefined signal for a right click on the button, but you can subclass QPushButton and emit your own signal in the `mousePressEvent()`.

```
class Button(QPushButton):

    right_clicked = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        super().mousePressEvent(event)
        if event.button() == Qt.RightButton:
            self.right_clicked.emit()
```

And it will respond with:

```
button = Button(root)
button.right_clicked.connect(pressed_mouse2)
```

Comment: Oh i forgot to type in the right function name, but thats not what i asked for, what is the name of signal that detects when the user clicked MOUSE2 on the button, but thanks for the documentation, i'll look into it.

Comment: @votka35 What is MOUSE2? I don't understand what "detects when the user clicked MOUSE2 on the button" means.